# UMVUE of $\sum_i \frac{\mu_i^2}{n}$ for non identical normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $Y_i \sim N(\mu_i,1)$ and $g(\mu_i) = \frac{\sum_i \mu_i^2}{n}$. $Y_{i's}$ are independent. Find the UMVUE from $g(\mu_i)$.

I know that the distribution belongs to the exponential family and $ \sum_i x_i $ is a sufficient and complete statistic for $\mu_i$

\begin{align*}
     p(x,\mu_i,1) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i - \mu_i)^2\right) \\
     &= (2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\sum_i x_i^2}{2} +\sum_i\mu_i \sum_i x_i -\frac{\sum_i \mu_i}{2} \right)\\
     &= (2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\sum_i x_i^2}{2}\right)\exp\left(\sum_i\mu_i \sum_i x_i -\frac{\sum_i \mu_i^2}{2}\right)
    \end{align*}

but I'm stuck in realizing which UMVUE of $g (\mu_i)$, I was thinking of turning $ \mu_i $ into a vector or something, could someone help?

Comment: Sorry, could you make the statistical setting a little bit more precise? Your get samples from which distribution? You want to get an estimator for $g(\mu_i)$ *for all $i$*?

Comment: The $Y_i’s$ are from a normal non identical independent and i want a UMVUE for $g(\mu_i)$. Basically each normal has a different mean in this case

Comment: The joint density is proportional to $$\exp\left\{-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu_i)^2\right\}=\exp\left\{-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\mu_i\right\}$$

If you write $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\mu_i=x^T\mu$ for vectors $x$ and $\mu$, this only suggests the trivial fact that $x$ is sufficient for $\mu$.

Comment: Yeah, i try to put in canonical form but i stuck too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ is complete sufficient for $\mu_i$ is incorrect.

Define a random vector $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^T$ where $X_i$'s are independent $N(\mu_i,1)$ variables. Also let $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)^T$. Then density of $X$ at $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ is

\begin{align}
f_{\mu}(x)&\propto \exp\left\{-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu_i)^2\right\}
\\&=\exp\left\{-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\mu_i\right\}\quad,\,\mu\in\mathbb R^n
\end{align}

Since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\mu_i=x^T\mu$ and $f_{\mu}$ is a member of a regular exponential family, it follows that $X$ is complete sufficient for $\mu$. So you only have to find an unbiased estimator of $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mu_i^2$ based on $X$.

A reasonable place to start is from $E\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right]$.